# Неправильное отображение на хостинге CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, хостинг

Всем привет, делал правки по сайту на компе, все работало, залил файлы на хостинг (beget) и некоторые стили и половина JS не работает. Файлы все перепроверил, все скопировано правильно, что может быть? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможно причина в кэше. Попробуй почистить кэш в браузере. (ctrl + f5)

Comment: Еще одна возможная причина - 
https://vc.ru/39538-reg-ru-lishil-partnerskogo-statusa-hosting-provaydera-beget-za-grubye-narusheniya

Comment: не, был сайт на бегет, заказчик попросил внести изменения, картинки поменялись и часть JS тоже, но некоторые части скрипта и CSS не работают

Comment: Попробуй нажать комбинацию ctrl + F5

Comment: прокси-сервер  также может кэшировать

Comment: Спасибо большое, помог CTRL+F5

Comment: Попробуйте добавить соли в адреса скриптов и стилей. src="myscript.js?ver=blabla". Это заставит кеш думать, что это другой урл и перечитать.